# render nested json in datatable

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

I am using a specific nested json to render some chart ( donuts chart .. ) and I wanted to use this same json to render date in a datatable 
here is a short version of my json

```
{
   "demXXXX": {
      "252XXXXX_101558406XXXX": {
         "name": "XXXX dans sa vie",
         "type": "link",
         "created_time": "2018-02-13 21:30:10",
         "link": "2018-02-13 21:30:10",
         "full_picture": "https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAUUQ601MwIe120&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxea_shutterstock-xxxx.jpg&_nc_hash=AQCBX_V4ErKqeVvs",
         "nb_shares": 105,
         "description": "xxxx",
         "click_publication": 6254,
         "getting_touch": 124083
      },
      "2526XXXXX_10155840181XXXXX7": {
         "name": "Black PXXXX",
         "type": "video",
         "created_time": "2018-02-13 21:00:00",
         "link": "2018-02-13 21:00:00",
         "full_picture": "https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAUUQ601MwIe120&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxea_shutterstock-xxxx.jpg&_nc_hash=AQCBX_V4ErKqeVvs",
         "nb_shares": 101,
         "description": "",
         "click_publication": 7828,
         "getting_touch": 224762
      },
      "nb_posts": 16,
      "nb_posts_link": 10,
      "nb_posts_images": 0,
      "nb_posts_videos": 6,
      "total_nb_personnes_atteintes": 4273856,
      "total_nb_videos_vues": 1323347,
      "total_reactions": 26368,
      "total_commentaires": 25510,
      "total_partages": 6536,
      "nb_clic_publications": 332275
   },
   "demXXXX_food": {
      "91313XXXX_166327179376XXX": {
         "name": "C'est offiXXX",
         "type": "link",
         "created_time": "2018-02-13 19:30:00",
         "link": "2018-02-13 19:30:00",
         "full_picture": "https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAUUQ601MwIe120&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxea_shutterstock-xxxx.jpg&_nc_hash=AQCBX_V4ErKqeVvs",
         "nb_shares": 12,
         "description": "",
         "click_publication": 0,
         "getting_touch": 55039
      },
      "913138XXXX_1663222XXXX1": {
         "name": "Pour lxxXX",
         "type": "video",
         "created_time": "2018-02-13 17:30:01",
         "link": "2018-02-13 17:30:01",
         "full_picture": "https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAUUQ601MwIe120&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxea_shutterstock-xxxx.jpg&_nc_hash=AQCBX_V4ErKqeVvs",
         "nb_shares": 2744,
         "description": "",
         "click_publication": 0,
         "getting_touch": 952160
      },
      "nb_posts": 4,
      "nb_posts_link": 3,
      "nb_posts_images": 0,
      "nb_posts_videos": 1,
      "total_nb_personnes_atteintes": 1242444,
      "total_nb_videos_vues": 274007,
      "total_reactions": 7760,
      "total_commentaires": 4348,
      "total_partages": 3009,
      "nb_clic_publications": 0
   },
}
```

I success to render in a datatable like that :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "analy/test.php",
    data: {timer : timer, page : page},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var page_name = i;
            $.each(item , function(key , value){

                if(typeof(value) == 'object'){

                    var images_post = value.full_picture;
                    var name_post = value.name;
                    var personnes_atteintes_post = value.getting_touch;
                    var reactions_post = value.reactions;
                    var commentaires_post = value.comments;
                    var partages_post = value.nb_shares;
                    var clic_publications_post = value.click_publication;
                    var type_post = value.type;
                    var vues_video = value.view_video;
                    var total_interaction = reactions_post + commentaires_post + partages_post ;

                    $('#table-post').append('<tr class="data-row"><td><img src='+images_post+' width="250"></td><td><a href = "http://www.facebook.com/'+key+'" target="_blank">'+name_post+'</a></td><td>'+personnes_atteintes_post+'</td><....</tr>');
                }   

            })

        });
    }
});
```

But my problem is when I have many results like 10K rows to render my browser is freezing so I think I have to use the Deferred loading of data to fix my issue but I don't think I can with my json structure

Comment: do you have the full url to the data so i can look at this? the sample data is pretty short so it won't have the same load time as your 10K records

Comment: If you have 10K rows you should defently look at serverside processing. defer render or deferred loading will not make any significant difference.

Comment: I found on a short code on jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/96ogaw98/

Do you think I can use it with my json structure ?